# swift3.0 Cannot convert value of type '[UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>]' to expected argument type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>?'

Tags: c, swift3, swift2, unsafemutablepointer

This code worked well in Swift2.3 and now I am converting it to Swift3. So I am getting this error. Anyone has idea, how to fix this?

```
var cmdLnConf: OpaquePointer?
fileprivate var cArgs: [UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>]

public init?(args: (String,String)...) {

    // Create [UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>].
    cArgs = args.flatMap { (name, value) -> [UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>] in
        //strdup move the strings to the heap and return a UnsageMutablePointer<Int8>
        return [strdup(name),strdup(value)]
    }

    cmdLnConf = cmd_ln_parse_r(nil, ps_args(), CInt(cArgs.count), &cArgs, STrue)

    if cmdLnConf == nil {
        return nil
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7Njy.jpg)

Comment: Please don't use images in place of code; paste the code into your question.

Comment: Also, the title of your question gives you the answer...

Comment: sorry I'm a newbie of swift to c.I have totally no idea how to fix it.Can you help me?

Comment: The error is telling you that instead of `[UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>]` it's expecting `UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>`, (so without the brackets)...

Comment: but this is right in swift2.3 and if I delete the brackets there are many other errors appearing- -!

Comment: And we are supposed to guess what the errors are? Swift 3 has changed quite a lot since Swift 2.x, so you'll have to change your code...

Comment: I have no idea what to do ...

Comment: where is cmd_ln_parse_r from? do you have some documentation about it?

Comment: I downloaded it form https://github.com/tryolabs/TLSphinx And cmd_ln_parse_r is cmd_ln_parse_r(cmd_ln_t *inout_cmdln,arg_t const *defn,int32 argc,char *argv[],int32 strict); please help me

Comment: there are more errors in your code, at least you didn't free the memory allocated by strdup. I am going to check your link to see the function ...

Comment: thank you very much thank you for helping me

Comment: try   return cArgs.withUnsafeBytes {
        cmd_ln_parse_r(nil, ps_args(), CInt(cArgs.count), $0, STrue)
    }    no guarantie!

Comment: thank you very much but there is another error "Cannot convert value of type 'UnsafeRawBufferPointer' to expected argument type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>?>!'"

Comment: ok ... so try  return withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &cArgs[0]) { return cmd_ln_parse_r(nil, ps_args(), CInt(cArgs.count), $0, STrue) } and let me know, what will be the error :-)

Comment: the error is "Cannot convert value of type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<_>' to expected argument type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>?>!'"

Comment: ??? put the code withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &cArgs[0]) { print(type(of: $0)) } there and return jus nil. and let me know, what is printig out.

Comment: print is "UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>>".I also think this is right but there is still error in xcode.......

Comment: ok, but now it really seems, that the required C parameter is char *p[] ... where did you find the info in your link? do you try to convert the project there to swift3?

Comment: it's in the file named "cmd_ln.h" and I have already converted it to swift3 and I got these errors.

Comment: ok, see the final answer :-)

Comment: @l'L'l sometimes the reporting error doesn't reflect the reality ... as in this case.

Comment: @user3441734 thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on our discussion it seems that parameter in your C function should be `char *p[]`

I made a small test

```
//
//  f.h
//  test001
//

#ifndef f_h
#define f_h

#include <stdio.h>

void f(char *p[], int len);

#endif /* f_h */
```

I defined the function with some basic functionality

```
//
//  f.c
//  test001

#include "f.h"

void f(char *p[], int len) {
    for(int i = 0; i<len; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", p[i]);
    };

};
```

with the required bridging header

```
//
//  Use this file to import your target's public headers that you would like to expose to Swift.
//

#include "f.h"
```

and swift 'command line' application

```
//
//  main.swift
//  test001
//

import Darwin

var s0 = strdup("alfa")
var s1 = strdup("beta")
var s2 = strdup("gama")
var s3 = strdup("delta")


var arr = [s0,s1,s2,s3]
let ac = Int32(arr.count)


arr.withUnsafeMutableBytes { (p) -> () in
    let pp = p.baseAddress?.assumingMemoryBound(to: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>?.self)
    f(pp, ac)
}
```

it finally prints

```
alfa
beta
gama
delta
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

based on the result, your have to use

```
let count = CInt(cArgs.count)
cArgs.withUnsafeMutableBytes { (p) -> () in
    let pp = p.baseAddress?.assumingMemoryBound(to: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>?.self)  
    cmdLnConf = cmd_ln_parse_r(nil, ps_args(), count, pp, STrue)
}
```

WARNING!!!
don't call `cArgs.count` inside the closure, where the pointer is defined!